# Unable to import WSO2ISschema into openldap

Tags: openldap, apacheds, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to import wso2person.ldif (http://pastebin.com/kvGX2RWr) into openldap 2.4.4. I see that openldap expects ldif file to contain different elements from what I have. However I can import the same ldif files in to ApacheDS.

I see the following error.

```
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
modifying entry "cn=schema"
ldap_modify: Invalid syntax (21)
        additional info: attributeTypes: value #0 invalid per syntax
```

Do i need to manually convert the ldif file or is there an utility that does the conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually edited those schema files to match what is expected by openLDAP